# How do I stop the instantiation of ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener?

Tags: spring-boot

I start my spring-boot application, and the `initialize()` method of `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener` is called, how do I stop it?